# AWS: password is not available

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created EC2 windows instance,
after I stopped the server, I try to restart server and connect to it.
After server started, I try to get the password in the follow way:

1. I pressed the "Connect" button

[image]

2. Selected **RDP Client** and **Get password**

[image]

In this case, I get the message:

[image]

I wait more than 20 minutes, but anyway this message still appeared

How can I get the password to the server after server reloading?

Comment: You might also want to try using the awscli [get-password-data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/get-password-data.html). Does it fail with an error message? Not sure this is relevant, but you should resolve the security group issue.

Comment: @jarmod How can I use awscli if I can't get to the server?

Comment: You run awscli locally, on your laptop. I don't expect it to succeed, but am wondering if it provides you with a more useful diagnostic error message.

Comment: @jarmod I can run/use awscli from aws.amazon.com site?

Comment: Download [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), install, configure, and run it. All the instructions you need are online.